# Tap sound from button missing UWP - Windows 10

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

I've just implemented a custom keyboard for a UWP Windows 10 app and while that part is working great, I just noticed there is no tapping sound when I tap on any of the buttons/keys.

Is there a built-in feature I'm missing here or is it just not available? I've been looking around for a tapping sound in order to simulate it if I have to, but I haven't found anything that's appropriate. Ideally I'd like to use the same one provided with a WP10 phone.

Any ideas as to whether either sound resources are available or is there some built-in feature I can use to enable sounds when a button is tapped?

**UPDATE:**

Apologies to all if I wasn't clear on this, and really appreciate the feedback but I'm not looking for code on how to play sound in C# or XAML. All I am looking for is:

1. Whether or not I did not spot a simple, yet obvious feature on how to turn on the `Default OS`sound for a button i.e. XAML or SDK?
2. Whether or not a WP10 Sound resources is available?

And based on one of the answer below, it looks like it's no for both of them!

Comment: Funny how you notice things late, but sound only appear on your "PIN" screen, but the likes of the calculator app does not have any tapping sound, so I guess it is a standard behaviour from apps and the odd one out is the login screen.

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for that but at least it could be interesting for you. However, keep in mind that it is preview feature and it is available since a specific version of SDK. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/sound

Comment: @kubakista While I can't tell for sure since I can't get it to work, it does sound like this is exactly what I'm looking for! No point installing it as it is in preview and even Microsoft recommends to only install this on a test machine and since I need this for an app that's about to be released in the MS Store, it's unfortunately a definite no! Thanks for sharing btw, shame it's in preview. Do you have any ideas as to when it will be released officially? I couldn't find anything in that regard.

Comment: I think it should be released within Windows 10 Anniversary Update - August 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Xaml Behaviors SDK` and `PlaySoundAction`

```
<Button x:Name="button3" 
        Content="Play Sound 3" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Margin="0,0,0,0" 
        d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" 
        FontSize="20" 
        Foreground="{StaticResource PaleGreyBrush}" 
        Background="{StaticResource DarkGreyBrush}" 
        Style="{StaticResource ActionsButton}" 
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=button3}">
                    <Media:PlaySoundAction Source="Assets/Whistle.mp3" Volume="1"/>
                </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Valid source and sample code: [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors)

Answer (score 1):

Pressing a button doesn't produce any audio feedback - only OS overlays like the keyboard (and hence, the PIN one you mentioned, along with the alphanumeric keyboard that shows when you tap on a `TextBox` control) do this.

However, you can easily reproduce the same behaviour by following these steps:

- Add a [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187272.aspx) to the page you have your keyboard on.
- Set its `Source` property to a WAV or MP3 sound you have packaged with the application.
- From your code behind, obtain a reference to the `MediaElement` control and call its `Play` method every time a button is pressed.

Regarding the actual sound effects, you may find an appropriate one in [OpenGameArt](http://opengameart.org/art-search-advanced?keys=&field_art_type_tid%5B%5D=13&field_art_tags_tid_op=and&field_art_tags_tid=ui&name=&sort_by=created&sort_order=DESC&items_per_page=24&Collection=) or you can try creating your own ones with [bfxr](http://www.bfxr.net/).

Comment: As my custom keyboard is a numeric keypad, I would have liked to provide the tapping sound with the MediaElement. I just hoped that there might have been a built-in feature or at least a resource that could have been used to be compliant and use the same sound as they OS overlays. I'll have a look OpenGameArt and see if there's anything that's acceptable.